# Show value if update isset

Tags: php, html, input

I am trying echo value in input field if update is set, something like this in code belove.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputTitle" id="InputTitle" placeholder="Enter title" <?php if (isset($_GET['update'])) { echo 'value="<?php echo $list['naslov'] ?>"' } ?> required>
```

I get some error but i can't figure it out? Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$list' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeCollect\insert.php on line 39

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Missing `;`.

No need of `echo` inside another `echo` - `echo 'value="<?php echo $list['naslov'] ?>"'`

Only `echo 'value="' . $list['naslov'] .'"'` will work.

Try with -

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputTitle" id="InputTitle" placeholder="Enter title" <?php if (isset($_GET['update'])) { echo 'value="' . $list[naslov] . '"'; } ?> required>
```

Comment: now it echo "<?php echo $list[naslov] ?>" in input field,i want to echo value of $list[naslov]

Comment: It is working now. Here is the code <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputTitle" id="InputTitle" placeholder="Enter title" <?php if (isset($_GET['update'])) { echo 'value="' . $list['naslov'] . '"'; } ?> required>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputTitle" id="InputTitle" placeholder="Enter title" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['update'])) { echo  $list['naslov'] }?>" required>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to close if with curly bracket

Comment: Yeah. minor mistake. :) have edited my answer

Comment: why is the answer not accepted.? didnt it work?

Comment: Nope, didn't worked...only the answer above is working but anyway thank you for help